# Using special characters in dictionary values in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having a use case where I need to pass a value which is having semi colons and colons for a key in a python dictionary. But it gives me a syntax error. Seems like this does not happen if the value is enclosed in double quotes instead of conventional single quote. Is there a way to impose that? Or, some other work around?

Here is the error -

```
props = {'creds1':'UserListings;service;SomeValue;Username:Mohan;Password:passkey123','creds2':''UserListings2;service;SomeValue2;Sample:Sikander;Password:passkey123'}
```

File "", line 1
    monProps = {'creds1':'UserListings;service;SomeValue;Username:Mohan;Password:passkey123','creds2':''UserListings2;service;SomeValue2;Sample:Sikander;Password:passkey123'}
                                                                                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a superfluous `'` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

use escape for special characters:

```
props = {'creds1':'UserListings;service;SomeValue;Username:Mohan;Password:passkey123','creds2':'\'UserListings2;service;SomeValue2;Sample:Sikander;Password:passkey123'}
print(props)
```

output:

```
{'creds1': 'UserListings;service;SomeValue;Username:Mohan;Password:passkey123', 'creds2': "'UserListings2;service;SomeValue2;Sample:Sikander;Password:passkey123"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
props = {'creds1': 'UserListings;service;SomeValue;Username:Mohan;Password:passkey123',
         'creds2': 'UserListings2;service;SomeValue2;Sample:Sikander;Password:passkey123'}
```

Or, if you genuinely have a quote in your text, you can escape as so:

```
props = {'creds1': 'UserListings;service;SomeValue;Username:Mohan;Password:passkey123',
         'creds2': '\'UserListings2;service;SomeValue2;Sample:Sikander;Password:passkey123'}
```

Alternatively, to use just single quotes within strings, as you mention double quotes will work:

```
props = {"creds1": "UserListings;service;SomeValue;Username:Mohan;Password:passkey123",
         "creds2": "'UserListings2;service;SomeValue2;Sample:Sikander;Password:passkey123"}
```